# hProduct Microformat not working in Google

Tags: html, google-rich-snippets-tool, microformats

I’m trying to work with **hProduct**.

```html
<div class="hproduct">
  <span class="brand">ACME</span> <span class="fn">Executive Anvil</span>
  <img class="photo" src="http://microformats.org/wiki/skins/Microformats/images/logo.gif" />
  <span class="review hreview-aggregate">
    Average rating: <span class="rating">4.4</span>, based on <span class="count">89
      </span> reviews
  </span>

  Regular price: $179.99
  Sale: $<span class="price">119.99</span> (Sale ends 5 November!)

  <span class="description">Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is 
    perfect for the business traveler looking for something to drop from a height.</span>

  Category: <span class="category">
    <span class="value-title" title="Hardware > Tools > Anvils">Anvils</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets only recognizes the `rating`, but not `photo`/`price`/`category`, but it still shows this warning:

> **warning: In order to generate a preview with rich snippets, either
>   price or review or availability needs to be present.**

The tool does not show the price and also does not show the picture:

> [image: Example snippet]

I used [Google’s own example](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186036).
I also tested the [example from microformats.org](http://microformats.org/wiki/google-rich-snippets-examples).

With Microdata I managed to display the price, but I really want to use Microformats.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is your example HTML in the testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=&html=%3Cdiv+class%3D%22hproduct%22%3E%0D%0A++%3Cspan+class%3D%22brand%22%3EACME%3C%2Fspan%3E+%3Cspan+class%3D%22fn%22%3EExecutive+Anvil%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A++%3Cimg+class%3D%22photo%22+src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmicroformats.org%2Fwiki%2Fskins%2FMicroformats%2Fimages%2Flogo.gif%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A++%3Cspan+class%3D%22review+hreview-aggregate%22%3E%0D%0A++++Average+rating%3A+%3Cspan+class%3D%22rating%22%3E4.4%3C%2Fspan%3E%2C+based+on+%3Cspan+class%3D%22count%22%3E89%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Fspan%3E+reviews%0D%0A++%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++Regular+price%3A+%24179.99%0D%0A++Sale%3A+%24%3Cspan+class%3D%22price%22%3E119.99%3C%2Fspan%3E+%28Sale+ends+5+November!%29%0D%0A%0D%0A++%3Cspan+class%3D%22description%22%3ESleeker+than+ACME%27s+Classic+Anvil%2C+the+Executive+Anvil+is+%0D%0A++++perfect+for+the+business+traveler+looking+for+something+to+drop+from+a+height.%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++Category%3A+%3Cspan+class%3D%22category%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cspan+class%3D%22value-title%22+title%3D%22Hardware+%3E+Tools+%3E+Anvils%22%3EAnvils%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A++%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E).
Works perfectly fine for me, with everything you say is a problem recognized, and no warning:

[image]

The example code from Google's docs *does* display the warning, but that's because of a syntax error which is breaking the markup:

```
<img class="photo" src="anvil_executive.jpg />
```

Note the `src` attribute is missing a closing quote. If you fix that, the warning goes away.

Comment: that picture you posted is the data extracted
and not the search result. No show photo: http://i.imgur.com/OvR6m.png

Comment: Your question never mentioned the problem was with live search, only with the testing tool. In fact, this is *still* the case. Anyway, the standard disclaimer applies here: "[Google doesn’t guarantee to use your markup](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170&topic=21997&ctx=topic)." (Scroll to the bottom.) The testing tool shows your code is correct, and that's as far as you go. Google gets to decide what if anything they actually want to do with it.

Comment: I put the image in question is the tool! With Microdata I managed to display the price,
but I really want is to use microformat.

Comment: I understand that. But you don't get to choose what of your data Google displays. As I've already explained, they make no promise they'll use any of it at all.

Comment: I understand that. But with Microdata google shows the price. Got it?

Comment: Unless you can provide some documentation *from Google* saying their behavior is always fully equivalent, you shouldn't assume the fact that it displays when you use microdata tells you anything about whether it'll display when you use hProduct. No matter how many adjustments you make to your question, the answer is not going to change: no guarantees. There's a reason they keep pointing it out in almost all their documentation for various things.

Comment: If the price is what's important to you, and you know it shows with microdata, then switch back to microdata. It's [what they recommend](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170), anyway. (See under "Pick a markup format.")

Comment: I understood it all,
but as it became clear, even you are sure.
I believe it is some error in the HTML. I'll wait for now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Google shows photo only for specific types of shema objects - ie. recipe, softwareapplication...
It is not displayed for normal product.

Comment: Can you provide a backing reference for that?

Comment: its not so simple :) you can check samples here http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173379&topic=1088474&ctx=topic but this changes over time. ie now softwareapplication doesn't have an image anymore in webmasters example, and in actual SERP ( https://www.google.pl/search?q=angry+birds+app ), probably due to abuse. Music on the other hand has a table http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1623047&topic=1088474&ctx=topic

Comment: @Łukasz Rysiak when answering a question answer it whole, and not part of it. I ask about: `photo`, `price`, `category` and the `warning` (Another thing I talked about Microdata also read the question again). You just answered on photo. I appreciate if you edit your answer.